# webMethods Integration Server is getting shutdown just after restart

Tags: unix, server, webmethods

I am trying to restart webMethods Integration Server by running `server.sh` file. In server log I can see just after restart, it  is getting shut down. Below is part of server log for which I think causing this error. How to solve this

```
2016-04-30 01:39:21:752 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] No registered exception delegate
2016-04-30 01:39:21:976 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002W] Unable to load logger from: com.webmethods.sc.mws.CDSJournalLogger
2016-04-30 01:39:21:993 EDT [ISS.0024.0012I] Central User Management initialized successfully.
2016-04-30 01:39:22:236 EDT [ISS.0014.0054C] Error occurred while initializing server: com.wm.util.coder.InvalidDatatypeException: [ISC.0076.9009] Root element is null at com.wm.util.coder.XMLCoder.decode(XMLCoder.java:280) at com.wm.util.coder.Coder.readFromFile(Coder.java:149) at com.wm.app.b2b.server.ACLManager.loadGenericAclMap(ACLManager.java:684)      at com.wm.app.b2b.server.ACLManager.loadWriteAcl(ACLManager.java:1679)  at com.wm.app.b2b.server.ACLManager.init(ACLManager.java:124)   at com.wm.app.b2b.server.Server.run(Server.java:350)
2016-04-30 01:39:23:240 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] MWS Shutdown Hook Shutting down...
2016-04-30 01:39:23:240 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] java.lang.Exception: SHUTDOWN
        at com.webmethods.portal.system.PortalSystem.shutdown(PortalSystem.java:912)
        at com.webmethods.portal.system.PortalSystem$1.run(PortalSystem.java:887)

2016-04-30 01:39:23:241 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: PortalServer
2016-04-30 01:39:23:241 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: postInit
2016-04-30 01:39:23:241 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: bizPolicy
2016-04-30 01:39:23:241 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: command
2016-04-30 01:39:23:247 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: bizPolicy
2016-04-30 01:39:23:247 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: mechanics
2016-04-30 01:39:23:247 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: mechanics
2016-04-30 01:39:23:252 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: CoreServices
Removing existing subscription: 15482016-04-30 01:39:23:269 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: portlet
2016-04-30 01:39:23:271 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: DataPhaseOne
2016-04-30 01:39:23:271 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: meta
2016-04-30 01:39:23:271 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: default
2016-04-30 01:39:23:272 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: cache
2016-04-30 01:39:23:274 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] JMSProvider.onReconnect entering for queues
2016-04-30 01:39:23:280 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: miePhaseTwo
2016-04-30 01:39:23:280 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: global
2016-04-30 01:39:23:281 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: cluster
2016-04-30 01:39:23:281 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Shutting down components of: miePhaseOne
2016-04-30 01:39:23:281 EDT [CommonLib.MWS.0002I] Stopped sending JDK log messages to Log4j
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server filesystem got full and all the ACL config files got corrupted. Restored the file from /config/backup and restrted the server. Server got restated fine.